# Eigenvalue, eigenvector, reflection on a plain in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question to the following task:

What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a reflection in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the $x_1$-$x_2$ plain.

Can someone give a source which answers this, or give a direct answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any desire to understand the question and come up with an answer on your own? If yes, there are many people here who will be delighted to help.

Comment: Yes, I do have a desire to understand the question and come up with an answer. I was asked this question by an other person so I have no real context, which made me ask it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are talking about the map $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto(x_1,x_2,-x_3)$. Am I right? Then its eigenvalues are $1$ (multiplicity $2$) and $-1$ (multiplicity $1$). Two linealy independent eigenvectors with the eigenvalue $1$ are $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, and an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$ is $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly I do not know which map is ment, but I think you are right. What do you mean with "multiplicity 2" and "multiplicity 1" for eigenvalues 1 and -1?

Comment: @Cornman If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a linear endomorphism $f$ of a vector space $V$, then the multiplicity of $\lambda$ is the dimension of the space $\{v\in V\,|\,f(v)=\lambda v\}$.